# What Apache Files Replaced in OS X Yosemite Upgrade

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

I just noticed my local server isn't working after my Yosemite upgrade. I had the same problem when I upgraded to Mavericks. I remember finding an answer in Stack Exchange documenting which which files had been replaced and the names of the saved originals. Sadly, I can't find that post. I know one is httpd.conf. I have three backups: httpd.conf.bak, httpd.conf.pre-update, and httpd.conf~previous. The last one has the most current creation date so I assume that's my last version. Is ~previous the naming convention that the Yosemite upgrade used? What other files have been replaced. There were only two last time IRC. In my search I've seen that I have to change htaccess directives, but, first, I want to get my old configs back.

Update

Replacing the config file with the old one didn't work. I then compared my old and new config files. There were quite a few changes so I applied my customizations to the new file. New I get 404 and 403 errors. That's a different issue. I would still like to know if any other files were replaced.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I've got my sites mostly back up. I think the php config file has been replaced as it's complaining about a setting I know I've corrected. I have a custom install of PHP. I have to figure out where it is. It's been too long since I've worked on it. I also can't get my WordPress page to display. I have no problem getting in WordPress Admin.